# How can port AsyncTask from Android to java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is very useful to synchronized between UI thread and other threads in Android. So I have read its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and tried porting to java classic (JDK) but no success because some classes don't exist in java (Message, Handler..). 
I would like to create a class with some useful functions like AsyncTask (that can synchronized between main thread and other threads) :

```
    doInBackground(Params... params)
    onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)
    onPostExecute(Result result)
    publishProgress(Progress... values)
    onPreExecute()
    onCancelled()
```

Is there any way to try that?

Comment: Have you had a look at [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which are more or less equivalent to AsyncTask in the JDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.** `AsyncTask` is specially developed for android to sync the UI thread and the Non-UI thread, also known as **Painless threading**.....

**2.** There is an alternative of AsyncTask in Java named as `SwingWorker`.

**See this link for a nice basic tutorial:**

http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-use-swingworker-to-perform-background-tasks/

Comment: +1. SwingWorker is probably the way to go if you're using Swing to build a UI.

Comment: Is this class only work for Swing UI? I tried use this class for console (for test) app, it never call doInBackground() method (although I used excute() method). Because I want to synchronized between main thread **(not only UI thread)** and other threads

Comment: If you are talking about Android..then an Android application starts on the Dedicated UI thread, consider this as the main thread. Whereas in Java GUI the JVM starts a Main thread, and put the main() method in the bottom of the stack of this Main thread. And as main() in JAVA GUI is not long lived, Event Dispatcher Thread handles it... Thats the reason we are recommended to keep the Non-UI work off the EDT thread. Now SwingWorker handles the sync between EDT (UI THREAD) and Non-UI thread.

Answer (score 14):

Agreed that `SwingWorker` is the most direct analog to `AsyncTask`

If you aren't using Swing, another option is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Here's an article demonstrating using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to spawn multiple background threads: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Spawning a single background thread that runs and completes *without* progress update (which is also a common use of `AsyncTask` in Android) can be as simple as:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // do stuff in background
  }
});
```

Comment: How to back to original thread? something like ```onPostExecute``` of ```AsyncTask```.

Comment: Using an Executor like this will only solve the problem of running your code in a background thread according to some strategy the Executor implements. Dispatching work back to the UI thread (or any other thread) still needs to be solved. Android solves this by dispatching messages / Runnables in the target thread's Looper via Handlers.

Comment: @ademar111190 It really depends on your specific use case. AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` is implemented by sending a message to a Queue, and the UI thread then executes the code when it receives the message.  `SwingWorker` has an analogous method `done()` inside of which one calls `get()` for the result of `doInBackground`. For more general Inter-Thread communication [`ConcurentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is a good place to start and depending on context you may have access to a higher level API of some sort also.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Observer design pattern for a similar situation. After spawning a background thread, the main thread goes into sleep mode. When the background thread finishes the asynchronous task, it wakes up the main thread with a callback message. This essentially removes a block on a synchronization object that was waiting for the callback.